# MySQL INNER JOIN USE

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_my_database |
+-----------------------+
| orders                | 
| orderTaken            | 
+-----------------------+
```

In orders, there are attributes like `orderId`, `orderName`.
In orderTaken, there are attributes like `userId`, `orderId` and `orderStatus`.

Basically, the mechanism of my project is running like:
A user with a unique userId will be able to take an order from the web page, where each order has its own unique `orderId` as well. After taken, the `orderTaken` table will record the userId, `orderId` and initially set `orderStatus = 1`.

Now, I want to select the orders taken by one user where the `orderStatus = 1`, but also I will need the orderName from my orders table to be shown. I've learned inner join and written a query as this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE orders.orderId IN
(SELECT orderId FROM orderTaken
WHERE orderTaken.userId = '8' AND orderTaken.orderStatus = '1')
INNER JOIN orderTaken ON orders.orderId = orderTaken.orderId
```

However, MySQL keeps complaining about syntax error. I guess I cannot use inner join this way? Can anybody correct me? Thanks!

Comment: Please remove the php tag as this has nothing to do with php

Comment: Oh yes sorry since I used php to execute query and it was there by default so I just left it there. I've removed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM orders
INNER JOIN orderTaken ON orders.orderId = orderTaken.orderId
WHERE orderTaken.userId = '8' AND orderTaken.orderStatus = '1'
```

You have over complicated it. This will work.

I have left the quotes in for the `userId` since I assumed that's right, but if they are of data type `INT` then you should remove them.

If you want some reading on `JOIN`s then see these links

- [Join terminology: inner, outer, semi, anti](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/19/introduction-to-joins/)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * 
   FROM (orders INNER JOIN ordersTaken ON orders.orderId = orderTaken.orderId) 
   WHERE orderId IN 
    (SELECT orderId 
     FROM orderTaken 
     WHERE orderTaken.userId = '8' AND orderTaken.orderStatus = '1')
```

Comment: Thanks ImmersionULTD! But after I run your query I get MySQL said: Documentation

#1052 - Column 'orderId' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous